# Email before download WordPress - No download link

Tags: wordpress, download, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add the option to download an e-book from a website using the plugin "E-mail before download". After filling out the form successfully I never get the download link. I do however, see the container in the inspector:

```
<div id="wpm_download_1" class="download-link" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Changing "display: none;" to "display: block;" didn't help.

I installed download manager and already had Contact form 7 running. Everything is set up like it should, as far as I know.

Could anyone give me advice as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the div has no other styling nothing will be shown on the screen, unless it has child elements contained within it. You may need to add other styling (e.g. height, width, etc) to show what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm that's not it. I already tried adding height, absolute positioning and colors. Besides there's a css file that covers most of the styles. This is just the html I thought was worth sharing to show that up to this point everything works.